# Sequelize field association does not work

Tags: database, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables. How to link field in first table with `id` field in second table in Sequelize?

First table:

```
tables.comments = sequelize.define('comments', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    text: Sequelize.TEXT,
    article: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    author: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: "users",
        referencesKey: "id",
        allowNull: false
    },
    answer: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    rating: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            tables.comments.belongsTo(tables.models.users, {foreignKey: 'author', targetKey: 'name'});
        }
    }
});
```

Second table:

```
tables.users = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    mail: Sequelize.TEXT,
    name: Sequelize.TEXT,
    pass: Sequelize.TEXT,
    status: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    rating: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    ban: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    key: Sequelize.TEXT
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            tables.users.hasMany(tables.models.comments, {foreignKey: 'author'});
        }
    }
});
```

I need to get tables.comments, but where instead of "author" will be the name of the author of the tables.users. I make request:

```
tables.comments.findAll({inclide: [{model: tables.users}]}).then(function(comments) {
    console.log(comments);
});
```

But in result in fields `author` only number, not name from `users`! 
Where is the mistake?

(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the associate classmethod, you'll want to use the column name of the table that the classmethod is defined in.  I'm assuming that the join condition is `comments.author = users.id`.

For your comments table, it would be:

```
tables.comments.belongsTo(tables.models.users, {
  foreignKey: 'author'
});
```

For your users table, it would be:

```
tables.users.hasMany(tables.models.comments, {
  foreignKey: 'id'
});
```